# Use refresh token grant type but keep existing refresh token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, doorkeeper

Using the [Doorkeeper Ruby gem](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper), I would like to get a new access token by sending a POST to `/oauth/tokens` with the body

```rb
{ grant_type: :refresh_token, refresh_token: 'abc123', scope: :A }
```

I do not want the response to include a replacement refresh token, however. Even if I explicitly set the config `use_refresh_token(false)`, the response always contains a new refresh token. Is there any way to avoid generating a new refresh token while using `grant_type: :refresh_token`?

The reason I'd like to do this is so that the client can request a JWT with fewer scopes, while still holding onto the existing refresh token with more scopes.

Answer (score 1):

The [refresh token rotation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-01#section-6.1) behaviour is becoming standard since it is part of OAuth 2.1 specs.

The refresh token should not lose any scopes though, and the behaviour should be like this. It is worth doing a quick test with Doorkeeper, via a couple of curl requests:

- At the time the user authenticates, Doorkeeper stores the scopes (which a user may have consented to) against the delegation - somewhere in its database. These may be scopes A, B and C.
- The client then chooses to do an access token refresh with only scope B. A new refresh token is returned, and an access token with reduced scopes.
- The client should still be able to do a new refresh, with the new refresh token, for scopes A, B and C again, since nothing has changed about the delegation.

Comment: The behavior I am seeing in Doorkeeper's implementation is that in step #2, the new refresh token has a smaller set of scopes than the the original refresh token (in your example, only scope B). This means that when I use the new access token, I have permanently lost access to scopes A and C.  I can't recover them with the old refresh token (because it has been revoked), nor with the new one (because it lacks those scopes). Am I missing something?

Comment: I would still try to use the new refresh token to try to get a new access token with all scopes - and see if that works. Only an access token uses scopes - the refresh token contents (if readable) should not matter - since the real scopes should be stored against the delegation in server state.